# Getting error on crontab manager in godaddy VPS server

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have VPS server with godaddy. I am trying to run a cron job but not able to execute it while I can run the same script from browser. I am pasting the message that I got from godaddy crontab manager. Also I am providing the command that I am using to run in cronjob.

```
0 0 * * *  /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php
```

I want the script named cron_delete_event.php to run everyday.

The error I am getting in email.

> /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php: line 1:
>   ?php : No such file or directory
>   /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php: line 2:
>   include: command not found
>   /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php: line 2: :
>   command not found
>   /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php: line 3:
>   syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php: line 3:`
>   $current_date = Date("Y-m-d"); '

Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the PHP executable:

```
0 0 * * * php /home/fyifuse1/public_html/cronjobs/cron_delete_event.php
```

You might need to use the full path to PHP which should be available in your control panel or FAQ.

See [Godaddy's page for setting up cron jobs](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3483/what-is-a-cron-job)

Comment: Thanks John for your answer. I did it.